# Simulink from workspace timeseries multiple datapoints each timestep possible?

Tags: matlab, function, time-series, block, simulink

I'm pretty new to Simulink and am working on a project. I have a couple of `MATLAB Function` blocks which works with vectors (of size 7200). My sources are `From  Workspace` blocks that so far have one time step (row) with 7200 datapoints (col). Now I want to simulate multiple time steps, hence I've constructed a time series matrix of 10 data points, but I want to "send" each row (time step) sequentially so that my Matlab fcn blocks works with a vector of size 7200, not all rows at the same time, [7200x10] which gives an error.

Any ideas how I can achieve this?

Comment: **1.** Take a step back. **2.** Define (to yourself and/or us) why you're using Simulink. **3.** Try and approach the problem *in Simulink* instead of *using MATLAB code inside Simulink*. Seems like you just want a script here...

Answer (score 0):

When using the `From Workspace` block the workspace data being read is expected to have a specific format.  That format depends on what data type is being used (i.e. Array, Timeseries, Structure With Time, etc.)

When using the Timeseries format, the first column is expected to be the (simulation) time at which the data in the other columns are to be read into the model.  So for instance, `sim_input_data` defined in the following way, would be read in as a 3 element vector (i.e. each ***row*** of the timeseries) at 0.2 second intervals (over a time period from 0 to 10 seconds).

```
>> sim_input_data = timeseries(randn(51,3),linspace(0,10,51))
  timeseries

  Common Properties:
            Name: 'unnamed'
            Time: [51x1 double]
        TimeInfo: [1x1 tsdata.timemetadata]
            Data: [51x3 double]
        DataInfo: [1x1 tsdata.datametadata]

  More properties, Methods
```

In your case, you need to correctly define the first column, and define the data in the timeseries as the transpose of the way you currently have it.